# using upload image with media_handle_upload .. but !

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm tring to upload image in wordpress by using some function ..

I found the way to upload images but there are one problem ..

when the user upload his image , wordpress create more than one image diffrent sizes, this is a problem because I want one image only ..

this is wp-conent/uploads/2010/10 folder .. look at the picture (this is one picture but wordpress create same picture but diffrent sizes) .

[image]

this is my code

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Uploading Page

*/?>

<?php get_header();
?><div class="container_12">
    <div id="content">
    <form id="file-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST">
    <p id="async-upload-wrap">
    <label for="async-upload">upload</label>
    <input type="file" id="async-upload" name="async-upload"> <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="html-upload">
    </p>

    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo '212';?>" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field('client-file-upload'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save all changes" name="save" style="display: none;">
    </p>
    </form>

<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['html-upload'] ) && !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
    $id = media_handle_upload('async-upload', 1199); //post id of Client Files page
    unset($_FILES);
    if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
        $errors['upload_error'] = $id;
        $id = false;
    }

    if ($errors) {
        echo "<p>There was an error uploading your file.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Your file has been uploaded.</p>";
    }
}

get_sidebar();
get_footer();?>

enter code here
```

how can make it one picture?

I wish you understand me ^** because my language >*<

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps you'll find something of relevance in the examples given here regarding the media uploader.

http://www.wptavern.com/forum/themes-templates/1346-creating-upload-function-options-page.html

You may also wish to consider posting your question to the [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: thank you very much .. I will put my question in wordpress stackexchange .. ^_^

Comment: linking to an outside page is not an answer. Perhaps summarize the answer for the benefit of the community and use a link a source to support your answer. Either way, this is not an answer and as mentioned by others, this link is dead.

Comment: The topic was far to large to summarize, if i felt i could have done so, i would have. The link is now a 404 though, so i'll give you the downvote on account of the information no longer being there.